# django imagekit - list view and details view image

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-imagekit

I have just started using django imagekit. I have a list view page where the images are of dimensions 270 x 203 (30 KB approx.) and same images have a size of 570 x 427 (90 KB approx.) in the details view page.

I wanted to know;

1. Should have create 2 different images for each image with different size and dimensions.
2. if the answer to the 1st query is yes. How to do it on Django Imagekit.

PS: I am planning to use django Imagekit on the form level.

Comment: Since the image ratios are _comparable_ to each other, you could store the higher image resolution, and display it as the smaller image using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by kicker86. I plan to retain single image.